# Laravel: Howto test file upload with a real file?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, file-upload, xunit

I got a controller and a request class to handle a simple file upload.
I am using a test method to test the functioning of the upload. So far so good.
The controller part, which does not get reached (because validation fails (`importfile needs to be a file.`)), looks like:

```
public function importCustomers(ImportCustomersRequest $request)
{
    dump('importCustomers called!');
```

The relevant parts of the request class `ImportCustomersRequest` is this:

```
public function rules(): array
{
    dump('importfile', $this->importfile);

    return [
        'importfile' => 'required|file',
    ];
}
```

The code used for testing is:

```
$file = UploadedFile::fake()->createWithContent('customer.csv', 'id;name;group\n9999;Customer1;');

// other approachs that did not work:
// $file = UploadedFile::fake()->create('customer.csv')
//
// testing with a real file would be ok too (the file exists!) - but nada (i receive the file content instead of an UploadedFile):
// $file = Storage::path('development/customers.csv')

$response = $this->post(route('import.customers', ['importfile' => $file]));
$response->assertStatus(302);
...
```

Dumping the importfile value in the request class using the upload via frontend (and a real file) yields a desired

```
Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#2053 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "customers.csv"
  -mimeType: "text/csv"
  -error: 0
  ...
```

Using the phpunit test from above gives me

```
array:2 [
  "name" => "customer.csv"
  "sizeToReport" => "67"
]
```

which obviously fails.

How am i able to upload a test file (preferably a real file with content) that passes validation (an `UploadedFile`)?

Comment: Have you checked and followed the manual: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#testing-file-uploads? They also create a fake storage.

Comment: You are literally uploading a "real file", this is the source code: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/b9203fca96960ef9cd8860cb4ec99d1279353a8d/src/Illuminate/Http/Testing/FileFactory.php#L34-L43, can you explain what are you expecting to get back?

Comment: @M.Eriksson: of course i did, but this did not solve my validation issue

Comment: @matiaslauriti: instead of an array i am expecting an Illuminate\Http\Testing\File to reach the Request class for validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem was easier solved than expected. I had to put the file content as a parameter of the request and not the route. See:

```
$file = UploadedFile::fake()->createWithContent('customer.csv', 'id;name;group\n9999;Customer1;');
$response = $this->post(route('import.customers'), ['importfile' => $file]);
```